# Laravel - Minimum one checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

So I have this code that gets all the checkbox texts and generates as much as there are in the database, but i want to have a minimum of one checkbox checked before the user can save settings.

```
<dl id="checkboxes">
                            @if($user->services)
                                @foreach($services as $service)
                                    <dd>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="chk{{ $service->id }}"  name="services[]" value="{{ $service->id }}"  {{  in_array($service->id, $user->services) ? 'checked' : ''}} />
                                        <label for="chk{{ $service->id }}">{{ $service->name }}</label>
                                    </dd>
                                @endforeach
                            @else
                                @foreach($services as $service)
                                    <dd>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="chk{{ $service->id }}"  name="services[]" value="{{ $service->id }}" />
                                        <label for="chk{{ $service->id }}">{{ $service->name }}</label>
                                    </dd>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </dl>
```

And, as this is a big form (profile settings) the button is in the end.

```
<button type="submit" class="custom-save-submt">@lang('Guardar')</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the checkbox values in your controller like so:

`$services = Input::get('services');`

Then you want to redirect if `$services` returns an empty array:

```
if (!$services) {
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg', 'Please select at least 1 service.']);
}
```

Or, using Laravel validation:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'services' => 'required',
]);
```

Comment: Sorry, new to Laravel, where do I put the laravel validation?

Comment: In your controller - so if you form POSTs to a page, set up a route at that address which links to a controller function